# Issue with php mysql login $_POST['username'] = $result['username']

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, authentication

I'm kinda' beginner and I've coded my own PHP login from Zero, but I still got some errors, here's the code:

```
        <?php 
    include 'connection.php';
    $query = " SELECT * FROM admin";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SELF_PHP']; ?>" method="post">
        Username : <input type="text" name="usernameInput" value="" />
        Password : <input type="password" name="passwordInput" value="" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>

    <?php
    $username = $_POST['usernameInput'];
    $password = $_POST['passwordInput'];
    if ($username = $result['username']) {
        if ($password = $result['password']){
            header('Location: admin.php');
        } else {
            echo "PASSWORD IS INCORRECT";
        }
    } else {
        echo "USERNAME IS INCORRECT";
    }
    ?>
```

So if you can fix this or got an easier way from PHP login from please tell me. :)

Comment: what errors you got ?

Comment: Several comments:if ($username = $result['username']) { should be if ($username == $result['username']) { Same for if ($password = $result['password']){. So use == in stead of = if you want to know something is equal. Second: don't use mysql. Use mysqli or prepared statements.

Comment: you need mysql_fetch_* functions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things...

1. Don't use `mysql` functions
2. You need to use `==` to compare strings, not `=`
3. You need to actually [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) the results of your query

   ```
   include 'connection.php';
   $query = " SELECT * FROM admin";
   $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); /* add this */

   ?>
   <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SELF_PHP']; ?>" method="post">
       Username : <input type="text" name="usernameInput" value="" />
       Password : <input type="password" name="passwordInput" value="" />
                   <input type="submit" value="Login" />
   </form>

   <?php
   if(isset($_POST['usernameInput']) && isset($_POST['passwordInput'])){
       $username = $_POST['usernameInput'];    
       $password = $_POST['passwordInput'];
   }
   else{
      echo 'some error ...';
   }

   if($username == $row ['username'] && $password == $row ['password']){
       header('Location: admin.php');
   } 
   else{
       echo ' username or password is wrong';
   }

   ?>
   ```

Comment: I can't see any potential SQL injection attack despide the `mysql_` functions being used;  only a static query is being made.

Comment: No escaping is needed for comparison

Comment: only when interpolated into a query

Comment: Fair enough, the mysql functions still should not be used -but he's right, if you're not inserting then you're not at risk. I assume though he uses these methods everywhere, so just a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

I have to point out that you are sending the same form over and over without first checking the post. And when you send the **form**, you will not be able to send the **header** to redirect, because html is started and headers are sent already.

Mysql functions are deprecated, please use mysqli interface.

Among other several bugs like assignment = instead of is equal ==

Try it this way:

If no post exists send the form else check and if ok redirect or not ok. resend the form

```
<?php 
if($_POST){
    include 'connection.php';
    $query = " SELECT * FROM admin";
    $r = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    // get an associated array from query result resource. 
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);  
    $username = $_POST['usernameInput'];
    $password = $_POST['passwordInput'];
    if (  ($username == $result['username'])
       && ($password == $result['password'])){
        header('Location: admin.php');
        exit(0);
    } else {
        echo "PASSWORD IS INCORRECT";
    }
} 
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SELF_PHP']; ?>" method="post">
    Username : <input type="text" name="usernameInput" value="" />
    Password : <input type="password" name="passwordInput" value="" />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

<?php

?>
```

Comment: I believe your curly brackets are unmatched